How are the MLE/MAP distinction and the generative/discriminative distinction related?
What is the relationship between Maximum Likelihood Estimation versus Maximum A Posteriori Estimation and generative modeling versus discriminative modeling?  Is MLE an example of a generative model and MAP an example of a discriminative model (or vice-versa)?  Does one distinction arise as a subdivision within only one choice of the other?  Are all four combinations of the pairs available choices for building an overall model?
The reason I'm a bit confused as to how they relate is that both pairs of choices seem to, roughly speaking, stand in a relation to each other of inverting the conditional probabilities involved, such as via Bayes' Theorem, but I am pretty sure (I think?) they're not pairs of synonyms for the same distinction.
How should I understand the relationship of these concepts?
